# Superagent Not Returning Value From Then

Tags: reactjs, fetch, axios, es6-promise, superagent

```js
superagent.get(URL).then((res) => {
  for(let i in res.body) {
    if (i==='has_rejected_advisories') {
      console.log(i + "="+res.body[i]);
    }
  }
})
.catch((err) => err.message));
```

My result is:

```js
has_rejected_advisories=false
```

But I am not able to use `res.body[i]` outside this function, i.e I want `superagent` function to return this value in a boolean variable to use it elsewhere.

ex.

```js
a = superagent.get(URL).then((res) => {
  for(let i in res.body) {
    if(i==='has_rejected_advisories') {
      console.log(i + "="+res.body[i]);
    }
  }
})
.catch((err) => err.message));

if(a===false){/*do this*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `superagent.get(url)` call is asynchronous. The value given to `a` is a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Since this is async, the `if (a === false)` is actually executing before the function body passed to `.then`. You will either need to move this logic to the `.then` function, or use something like [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if you like the synchronous looking syntax.

Comment: Yes you are right it is returning a promise, but taking my logic inside then will restrict the variables locally and it will break the code.
Ex.  .then(... if(a===false){map = /*some content*/})

map variable can't be used outside then() which is my requirement

Comment: I'd definitely recommend the `await` approach then. Once inside a promise's `.then` function, you really can't "escape" from it. Just be aware that it is only supported in [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=await). If you need backwards compatibility, you will need babel.

Answer (score 1):

On top of jerelmiller's great advice you need to note the following:

Try this:

create a global var assuming it's a string

```
 var mysares = ""
```

This example will only bring back 1 string back of everything!! Not single element. Also if you can't get the standard Fetch() to work don't try other methods like axios or superagents. Now use our global like so:

```
  superagent.get(URL).then((res) => {
      for(let i in res.body) {
        if (i==='has_rejected_advisories') {
          //Add comments as will help you
          //to explain to yourself and others 
          //what you're trying to do
          //That said if this iteration produces
          //correct data then you're fine
          //push my result as a string
          mysares = res.body[i];
          //infact what's in row 1?
          mysares = res.body[0];
          //Actually I code my own JSON!!
          mysares = res.body[1];
          console.log(i + "="+mysares);
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => err.message));
```

Now you can do whatever:

```
 if(mysares===false){/*do this*/
   alert(playDuckHunt());}
```

Things to note:
`res.body[i]` is an iteration
You cannot use it outside of the function
Because:
It's local to that function
You don't know what position of '`i`' is even if you could use it as you will be outside of your loop

One last thing:
Loops loop through loops or arrays etc.
So (in real world) you can't just request the value of the loop
unless you agree the position of data to be released,
type,and bucket (where it's going to be displayed or not).

Hope this helps!

PS> we need to know where 'has_rejected_advisories' is in the JSON so send us your json url as it must be a column/obj header name. Or it's any old 'a' then var a can be your "false"

Comment: var myshares="";
    superagent.get('***/api/profile/get-user-info/').
    then((res)=>
    {for(let i in res.body) {if (i === 'has_rejected_advisories'){if   (res.body[i]===false){console.log(i + " = " + res.body[i])};
    myshares= res.body[i];}}})
        .catch((err) => (err.message));

    console.log(myshares+" it is outside");

Result:

has_rejected_advisories = false

Comment: I have tried this approach but the value assigned is not used, it remains undefined if we use let or const.
The api can't be shared what are the specific information you need if you can tell me I will share them.

From the api:

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

"has_rejected_advisories": false,

Comment: You don't need let or const. A simple var will work as I mentioned your data has been passed to a simple string = myshares. Send your json so we can see. We need to know the full structure of the JSON!

Comment: Then you try something like: `myshares= res.body[i].has_rejected_advisories;`.

Comment: And yes it will remain undefined until you send back a string like so to the browser: `myshares= res.body[i].has_rejected_advisories;`. Because browsers mostly only can read strings. If you return `myshares= res.body[i]`; this is just an object which cannot be read by browser.

Answer (score 0):

In constructor:

```
this.state = {a:null};
```

In some function:

```
superagent.get(URL).then(
(res) => {for(let i in res.body) 
{
   if(i === 'has_rejected_advisories')
     {
        this.setState({a:res.body[i]})
     }
 }
  }).catch((err)=>(err.message));
```

In render:
    console.log(this.state.a);

Inside then() the value could be used using state variable but there are many scenarios we could not use them, like if we want to perform all the operations under constructor i.e Initializing state variable, calling superagent and changing the state variable and using the state variable.